# How can I solve type error when cloning an object in `typescript`?

Tags: typescript

I have below code. I have two types one is `MyType` the other is `MyTypeDto`. And I'd like to clone the instance of `MyType` to `MyTypeDto` but has a compile error on the assignment line: `Type 'string | boolean | Date' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

How can I solve the issue here?

```
interface MyType {
  str: string;
  bool: boolean;
  d: Date;
   ...
}

interface MyTypeDto {
  str?: string;
  bool?: boolean;
  d?: Date;
  name?: string;
  ...
}

const t: MyType = {
    str: "",
    bool: false,
    d: new Date(),
};

const keys = Object.keys(t);
const dto: MyTypeDto = {};

keys.forEach((key: string) => {
    dto[key as keyof MyTypeDto] = t[key as keyof MyType];  // error here
});
```

Comment: Why you use a loop to clone obj? How about `Object.assign(dto, t);`

Comment: there will be more fields in `MyType` which don't exist in `MyTypeDto`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that best way to achieve that. Is to make custom copy function.

```js
const copy = (myType: MyType): MyTypeDto => {
 const { str, bool } = myType;

 return {
   str,
   bool   
 }
}
```

You can also look at [Destructin syntax with rest](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/destructuring#object-destructuring-with-rest). Literally named after de-structuring i.e. breaking up the structure. That what you need right now.

For more than few properties. You can get interface keys using `ts-transform-keys` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys).

```js
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';

interface MyType {
  str: string;
  bool: boolean;
  d: Date;
}
const keysOfMyType = keys<MyType>();

console.log(keysOfMyType); // ['str', 'bool', 'd']
```

Comment: There are more than 60 fields in real case and it is something I want to avoid.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao added method that will work with multiple properties in interface